# Issue in showing multiple cells in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have two fields which takes the birthdate and anniversary date. Now if the birthdate or anniversary date comes within the next 30 days, I have to display them in a tableview. This I'm trying to achieve like so..

```
    let cell2: BestWishesTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "bdayWishesCellIdentifier") as! BestWishesTableViewCell

              if indexPath.row < customerDetails.count {

              let bdayObj = customerDetails[indexPath.row]

                if Calendar.current.isDateInNextThirtyDays(bdayObj.birthday!) {
                    cell2.nameLabel.text = bdayObj.fname

                    let formatter = DateFormatter()
                    formatter.dateStyle = .medium
                    formatter.timeStyle = .none
                    cell2.dateLabel.text = formatter.string(from: bdayObj.birthday!)
                } else if Calendar.current.isDateInNextThirtyDays(bdayObj.anniversary!) {
                    cell2.nameLabel.text = bdayObj.fname

                    let formatter = DateFormatter()
                    formatter.dateStyle = .medium
                    formatter.timeStyle = .none
                    cell2.dateLabel.text = formatter.string(from: bdayObj.anniversary!)
                }

                }

                else {
                let bdayObj = customerDetails2ArrTwo[indexPath.row - customerDetailsArrTwo.count]

   if Calendar.current.isDateInNextThirtyDays(bdayObj.birthday!) {
                cell2.nameLabel.text = bdayObj.fname

                let formatter = DateFormatter()
                formatter.dateStyle = .medium
                formatter.timeStyle = .none
                cell2.dateLabel.text = formatter.string(from: bdayObj.birthday!)
            } else if Calendar.current.isDateInNextThirtyDays(bdayObj.anniversary!) {
                cell2.nameLabel.text = bdayObj.fname

                let formatter = DateFormatter()
                formatter.dateStyle = .medium
                formatter.timeStyle = .none
                cell2.dateLabel.text = formatter.string(from: bdayObj.anniversary!)
            }
                   return cell2
            }
```

Here, in the first part, from `if indexPath.row < customerDetails.count` till before the `else` part, I take data from one table and in the else part I take data from another table. In the first part that I just mentioned, I'm checking if the birthday and anniversary date is within the next 30 days(Now in fact both bday and anniversary dates are within the next 30 days because thats what I've given). But it is showing just the birthday in the tableview and not the anniversary date while both dates should have been shown in the tableview.

Now since I've given `else if` I know it will execute just the 1st `if` condition. But even if I didn't use `else if` and used another `if` instead, then what happened was again just one cell(i.e. one date) was shown (and this time the anniversary date was shown) as the birthdate was overwritten by the anniversary date.

How can I make both birthdate and anniversary to appear together(i.e. 2 cells)...?

Comment: Can you show the code for your `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)` please?

Comment: the `numberOfRows..` is given as the sum of data in both tables like so..`count = (customerDetails.count) + (customerDetails2.count)`.

Comment: Hard code text in the cells and see if the labels are displayed. Set the background color to the UILabel. It could be a layout issue.

Comment: @v.bw -- you may be confusing the issue... Where are your two fields? Do you have a tableView with rows of customers, and each row has two fields, and based on dates entered in those fields you want to add rows in between?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the below.  Basically, you're expecting two rows for each object in the customerDetails array.  Then, use the row % 2 check to determine if it's even or odd

```
    if indexPath.row < customerDetails.count * 2 {

        let bdayObj = customerDetails[indexPath.row]

        if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
        if Calendar.current.isDateInNextThirtyDays(bdayObj.birthday!) {
            cell2.nameLabel.text = bdayObj.fname

            let formatter = DateFormatter()
            formatter.dateStyle = .medium
            formatter.timeStyle = .none
            cell2.dateLabel.text = formatter.string(from: bdayObj.birthday!)
            }
        } else {
            if Calendar.current.isDateInNextThirtyDays(bdayObj.anniversary!) {
                cell2.nameLabel.text = bdayObj.fname

                let formatter = DateFormatter()
                formatter.dateStyle = .medium
                formatter.timeStyle = .none
                cell2.dateLabel.text = formatter.string(from: bdayObj.anniversary!)
            }
        }
    }
```

However, that's not going to work well when you have a birthday or an anniversary in the next 30 days (i.e. not both).

To be honest with you, I think you need to revise how you're doing this.  You should build a clean array that contains one item for either birthday or anniversay (2 items if needed) which it's already checked if its in the next 30 days.  This way, you can just have a clean lookup in your cellforItemAt based upon indexPath.row.