# Showing data in same row in different tableview cells

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have stored 2 entries in coredata given like so(in the image)...

[image]

Here in the first row, the `fname` is `qwe` and `lastname` is `try`. And in the 2nd row, the `fname` is `awed` and `lastname` is `sdcv`. Typically if I try to populate these names in a tableview, I'll get in the first cell the name `qwe` and in the 2nd cell the name `awed`. But I want in the first cell the name `qwe` and in the 2nd cell the name `try`, How can I achieve this...?

The code for what would happen in a normal scenario would be something like so..

In `cellForRow`..

```
let cell2: BestWishesTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "bdayWishesCellIdentifier") as! BestWishesTableViewCell

let objCust = customerDetailsArrTwo[indexPath.row]
cell2.nameLabel.text = objCust.fname
```

The `numberOfRows` would be `customerDetailsArrTwo.count`

Comment: Use this code if 1st Cell is Firstname and 2nd cell is Lastname, 3rd cell 2nd object FirstName and 4th cell is 2nd object LastName and so on. `if indexPath.row %2 == 0 {
            cell2.nameLabel.text = objCust.fname
        }
        else {
            cell2.nameLabel.text = objCust.lname
        }`

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve ? Are there only 2 records ? Does the first cell display only ZFNAME and 2nd cell only ZLASTNAME ?

Comment: Actually @Nitish what I want is this..instead of `fname` & `lname` what I have is 2 dates `birthdate` & `anniversaryDate` and both of these are in the same row like the `fname` & `lname` I want to display both these dates in separate cells...

Comment: @v.bw cell hierarchy is same as I asked? like 1st cell is 1st object `birthdate` 2nd cell is 1st object `anniversaryDate`. 3rd cell is 2nd object `birthdate` 4th cell is 2nd object `anniversaryDate` and so on.

Comment: @Kuldeep what you suggested worked. Thanks. Do put it up as an answer so I can accept it. Also can you explain the line `if indexPath.row %2 == 0`

Comment: @v.bw - don't create duplicate questions... You posted (essentially) the same question yesterday, as well as about an hour-and-a-half before this one.

Comment: @v.bw, you already asked this question and someOne already gives you answer as I suggest you.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49493458/issue-in-showing-multiple-cells-in-tableview

Comment: Ok @Kuldeep Cool. But if you could just put it up I can maybe give an upvote...

Comment: @v.bw, If you got the solution than please remove duplicate questions.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code if 1st Cell is Firstname and 2nd cell is Lastname, 3rd cell 2nd object FirstName and 4th cell is 2nd object LastName and so on.

```
if indexPath.row %2 == 0 { 
    cell2.nameLabel.text = objCust.fname 
} 
else { 
    cell2.nameLabel.text = objCust.lname 
}
```